# How to add row values based on indicator within single row

Tags: mysql

Quick example to get the question started:

## Temporary Table Example

```
ID |  value   |  Flag  | parent
-------------------------------
1  |  12.50   |   1    |   19
2  |  13.50   |   1    |   20
3  |  14.50   |   2    |   1 
4  |  15.50   |   1    |   21   
5  |  16.50   |   1    |   22
6  |  17.50   |   1    |   23
7  |  18.50   |   2    |   2
8  |  19.50   |   1    |   24
```

ultimately, I want to search a table, for any ID with a flag of 2, take that value and add it to the associated parent ID.

The ideal results would return:

```
ID |  value   |  Flag  | parent
-------------------------------
1  |    27    |   1    |   19
2  |    32    |   1    |   20
4  |  15.50   |   1    |   21   
5  |  16.50   |   1    |   22
6  |  17.50   |   1    |   23
8  |  19.50   |   1    |   24
```

where 3 and 7 were removed, with their values added to their parent value (1 and 2 respectively). Keep in mind the parent field is already being pulled from an Inner JOIN with another table (the table above is generated based on two tables).

The table above is created as a temporary table so no updates or table modifications can or will be made. I am looking to create a single select statement.

Answer (score -1):

Updated.

Assuming there the only possible values for `Flag` are 1 and 2:

```
INSERT temp_table (ID, Value, Flag, Parent)
SELECT MAX(IF(Flag = 1, ID, 0)), SUM(Value), 1, MAX(IF(Flag = 1, ParentID, 0))
FROM generated_query
GROUP BY IF(Flag = 1, ID, ParentID)
```

Depending on how you generate your query, you might get better performance using a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: not looking to update anything - this is a temporary table being used for other methods. The table I have drawn above does not exist and never will outside of temporary status.

Comment: there is no insert or update command when building the table from scratch and using in a single php statement and single mysql call. The table above IS what is generated by the single query - I am looking to build based off of that. It is safe to assume the flag exists elsewhere but there is no table. The table is immediately translated into rows and sorted with PHP for processing.

Comment: @jm4 so just use the `SELECT` part of the query.. or post your php code. thx for the downvote!

Comment: Not really the solution I am looking for but please update your answer to reflect the changes and I'll atleast give you credit. Note: your two answers did not answer mine, hence the downvote. Your downvote on the question just does not make sense.